# Understanding recursion and pre decrement

Tags: c, increment, decrement

Hi Can someone please explain this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    void myfunc(int x){
        printf ("  [%d]",x);
        printf ("M here 1\n");
        if (x > 0) myfunc(--x);
        printf ("M here 2\n");
        printf ("  %d,\n",x);
    }
    myfunc(5);
}
```

Output coming is:

```
[5]M here 1 
[4]M here 1 
[3]M here 1 
[2]M here 1 
[1]M here 1 
[0]M here 1 
0,M here 2   [0]
0,M here 2   [1]
1,M here 2   [2]
2,M here 2   [3]
3,M here 2   [4]
4,M here 2   [5]
```

However, I am stuck on how,

```
0,M here 2   [0]
0,M here 2   [1]
1,M here 2   [2]
2,M here 2   [3]
3,M here 2   [4]
4,M here 2   [5]
```

Isn't it should have stopped at

```
0,M here 2   [0]
```

Comment: `--x` decrements `x` *before* passing it to `myfunc()`

Comment: yeah, got that.. but am wondering, how x is incrementing after 1st 
    0,M here 2   [0]

Comment: @notbad.jpeg: `x` is no way passed to the function! C is strictly pass-by-value!

Comment: First it is descending to the innermost recursion level before it is returning from any of the recursive calls. Than it is starting to return from the inner one to the outer one, reversing the order of `x` values passed.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger.

Comment: @Ben I find it pretty difficult to understand the recursive flow in the debugger..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Maybe in a really complex recursive function, but with this, printing the stack trace and stepping the OP would have experienced all of the above comments themselves.

Comment: *To understand recursion, you must understand recursion* - Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion.

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't it should have stopped at

No, it shouldn't. After the recursive call returns, the function continues to execute the lines following that line.

---

Let's walk through the excuction of `myfunc` when the input is `2`. You can extrapolate it to higher value after that. When the function is called with `2`, you get:

```
printf ("  [%d]",2);
printf ("M here 1\n");
myfunc(1);               // Since 2 > 0
printf ("M here 2\n");
printf ("  %d,\n",1);    // You get 1 here since x is decremented.
```

When the function is called with `1`, you get

```
printf ("  [%d]",1);
printf ("M here 1\n");
myfunc(0);               // Since 1 > 0
printf ("M here 2\n");
printf ("  %d,\n",0);    // You get 0 here since x is decremented.
```

When the function is called with `0`, you get

```
printf ("  [%d]",0);
printf ("M here 1\n");
// No more recursion since the input is 0
printf ("M here 2\n");
printf ("  %d,\n",0);    // You get 0 here since x is NOT decremented.
```

Now, if you flatten the recursive calls, you get:

```
printf ("  [%d]",2);
printf ("M here 1\n");

   printf ("  [%d]",1);
   printf ("M here 1\n");

      printf ("  [%d]",0);
      printf ("M here 1\n");
      printf ("M here 2\n");
      printf ("  %d,\n",0);

   printf ("M here 2\n");
   printf ("  %d,\n",0);

printf ("M here 2\n");
printf ("  %d,\n",1);
```

It's easy to see why that will produce the output:

```
  [2]M here 1
  [1]M here 1
  [0]M here 1
M here 2
  0,
M here 2
  0,
M here 2
  1,
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code, I only changed the argument passed to `myfunc` in the main function and marked the different lines so it's easier to explain what happens :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  void myfunc(int x){
    printf ("  [%d]",x);      // [1]
    printf ("M here 1\n");    // [2]
    if (x > 0)                // [3]
      myfunc(--x);            // [4]
    printf ("M here 2\n");    // [5]
    printf ("  %d,\n",x);     // [6]
  }

  myfunc(2);                  // [7]
}
```

Here is what happens. In the first column which line of your code is executed, in the middle column, the context where it's executed and in the last one, the value of `x` within the current context.

```
                                Context               Value of x

[7] Call myfunc(2)              Main function         N/A
|                              
+-> [1] print                   1st call to myfunc    2
    [2] print                   1st call              2
    [3] x > 0 is true           1st call              2
    [4] x := x - 1              1st call              1
    [4] Call myfunc(x)          1st call              1
    |                          
    +-> [1] print               2nd call to myfunc    1
        [2] print               2nd call              1
        [3] x > 0 is true       2nd call              1
        [4] x := x - 1          2nd call              0
        [4] Call myfunc(x)      2nd call              0
        |
        +-> [1] print           3rd call to myfunc    0
            [2] print           3rd call              0
            [3] x > 0 is false  3rd call              0
            [5] print           3rd call              0
            [6] print           3rd call              0
            Retun               3rd call              0
            |
          <-+
        [5] print               2nd call to myfunc    0
        [6] print               2nd call              0
        Retun                   2nd call              0
        |
      <-+
    [5] print                   1st call to myfunc    1
    [6] print                   1st call              1
    Return                      1st call
```

If you take all the prints that are called with the corresponding value of x, you get :

```
[1] print 2        
[2] print 2        >   [2]M here 1
[1] print 1        
[2] print 1        >   [1]M here 1
[1] print 0        
[2] print 0        >   [0]M here 1
[5] print 0        > M here 2
[6] print 0        >   0,
[5] print 0        > M here 2
[6] print 0        >   0,
[5] print 1        > M here 2
[6] print 1        >   1,
```

In a recurrence, you have to keep in mind that every time you call a function inside itself, at some point, this call will return and the following statements will be executed normally. A good way to build/understand a recursive function is to see it not a an set of statements doing things "independently", but to see it as a whole instruction doing some job. That way, if you can write the specification of your function first, you know how to reuse it inside itself and if it's safe.